# The Union and Intersection of the Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the question, it's asked to find:$$\bigcup_{X=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb N)}{X}$$ and $$\bigcap_{X=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb N)}{X}$$Does this mean find the union and intersection of the power set of all natural numbers? Wouldn't the result be $\mathbb N$ for both cases since $\mathbb N$ is common for both sets. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Isn't Null a part of the power set and wouldn't the intersection of null with any other set be the null set

Comment: @KitterCatter I thought about that, but wouldn't all natural numbers be repeated for the intersection, including the null set?

Comment: The intersection consists of exactly those natural numbers that are in **all** subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. The union consists of exactly those natural numbers that are in **at least one** subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Is each natural numbers in at least one subset? If so, you are correct about the union; if not, then you are incorrect. Is each natural number in **all** subsets of $\mathbb{N}$? If so, you are correct about the intersection. If not, then yhou are incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean $X \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb{N})$ instead of $X = \mathscr{P}(\Bbb{N})$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x
&= \bigcup_{x \subseteq \mathbb{N}} x \\
&= \mathbb{N} \cup \bigcup_{x \subseteq \mathbb{N}} x \\
&= \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{x \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x
&= \bigcap_{x \subseteq \mathbb{N}} x \\
&= \varnothing \cap \bigcap_{x \subseteq \mathbb{N}} x \\
&= \varnothing
\end{align*}